# Arranging elements click priority

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, flexbox

I have the following code: (JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/cjpLa44m/2/)

```
<style>
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.everything {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.mainImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mainImg {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative
}
#canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="everything">
    <div class="mainImg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png"></div>
</div>

<script>
var canvas      = document.createElement("canvas");
var width       = innerWidth;
var height      = innerHeight;
var ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width    = width;
canvas.id = "canvas";
canvas.height   = height; 

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(width / 2, height / 2, 50, 50);

window.onload = function () {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    document.body.style.margin = "0";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";    
};

canvas.onclick = function(){
    alert("Canvas called, although it shouldn't");
}

var smile = document.getElementsByClassName("mainImg")[0];
smile.onclick = function(){
alert("i should be called");
}
</script>
```

I have an image which is centered upon the browser, and a canvas which is on absolute position, spreading across the entire screen.
In regards to display, the canvas has display priority over the image, and that's how I want it to be because I am using some transperent parts of the canvas to display the image aswell.

The problem is the clicking priority: as you can see, when you click on the smiley image the canvas' click function gets called, since it spreads on the entire screen. but in terms of clicking priority, I want my image to be called. can it be done?

thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: You can add another element on top of the canvas to accept the click.

Comment: in your fiddle, i can never trigger the simle.onclick, i.e. i always get only the alert from the canvas.onclick

Comment: emanek, that is exactly the problem i am talking about... please read my thread again. alexander - i didn't quite understand, sorry.

Comment: When I click on the fiddle then I can only get alert like `"i should be called"` and never got alert like `"Canvas called, although it shouldn't"`.. FYI - I am using Chrome. I have just separated css & javascript here - https://jsfiddle.net/cjpLa44m/4/

Comment: from what i see in your fiddle, the image has display priority over the canvas therefore the canvas is invisible, and that's why you see "i should be called". i want my canvas to be visible and on higher display priority, but simply not to overtake the click event of the smiley. just embed the entire code to an .html file and you will see the results i get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to your `#canvas` rule, it will pass the click through to the image

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjpLa44m/5/)

Comment: @RunningFromShia Updated my answer with a link when you click on the the word _pointer-events_, but simply put, `pointer-events: none` removes the mouse events from the elements, so it behaves like it is not even there.

Answer (score 1):

The event can not bubble as you have the image and the canvas in separate unrelated elements. If you place the canvas in the same containing element as the image the click event will bubble from one to the next

Also you are best of using `addEventListener` rather than directly assigning the event listener to the `onclick` property.

In your HTML

```
<div class="everything">
    <div class="mainImg" id="contain">
        <img src="smile.png">
    </div>
    <!-- this is where the canvas will go -->
    <div id="canvasContainer"></div> <!-- add this div to hold the canvas -->
</div>
```

Then when you add the canvas add it to the container, rather than the `document.body` then add the event listeners.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(canvas);
    var smile = document.getElementsByClassName("mainImg")[0];
    smile.addEventListener("click",imageEvent);
    canvas.addEventListener("click",canvasEvent,true); // last arg true to capture the event (ie get it first)
};
```

When you do this and you want the canvas to get the event first you must set the event capture flag to `true`.

```
canvas.addEventListener("click",canvasEvent,true); // last argument true
```

if you set it to `false`

```
canvas.addEventListener("click",canvasEvent,false); // last argument false
// or
canvas.addEventListener("click",canvasEvent); // or defaults to false
```

Then the image element (under the canvas) will get the event first.

The event listeners

```
function imageEvent(e){ alert("Image") } // not much to do 
// the canvas event you need to either prevent the event bubbling
// or let it through depending on what your needs are.
function canvasEvent(e){
    if( /*only for canvas */){
       alert("Canvas handling it");
       e.cancelBubble = true;
    }else{
       alert("Canvas is passing the event onto the image");
    }
};
```